# What are the advantage and disadvantages of using a list comprehension in Python 2.54-6?

Tags: list-comprehension, python-2.6, python-2.5

I've heard that list comprehensions can be slow sometimes, but I'm not sure why? I'm new to Python (coming from a C# background), and I'd like to know more about when to use a list comprehension versus a for loop. Any ideas, suggestions, advice, or examples? Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a list comprehension (LC) when it's appropriate.

For example, if you are passing any ol' iterable to a function, a generator expression (genexpr) is often more appropriate, and a LC is wasteful:

```
"".join([str(n) for n in xrange(10)])
# becomes
"".join(str(n) for n in xrange(10))
```

Or, if you don't need a full list, a for-loop with a break statement would be your choice.  The [itertools](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html) module also has tools, such as takewhile.

Comment: Thanks for the response Roger! Great example.